# Increasing the distance in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot(data = sortmax, aes(x = Date, y = price, colour = Grade)) +geom_line(aes(group = Grade)) + geom_point()
```

I have five different graphs for five different grades . All the graphs are intersecting and over writing each other because of common values of price on y axis. How can I increase the distance between all these graphs ?

Comment: Help us help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I cannot add image due to a reputaion of lessthan 10

Comment: No, but you can add data. Read the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be useful if you can post output of command: dput(sortmax)

You can try separating the graphs completely by using facet_grid:

```
ggplot(data = sortmax, aes(x = Date, y = price, color=Grade)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point()+
    facet_grid(Grade ~ .)
```

Comment: using facet_grid(Grade ~ .) throws error message "At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting" . I cannot show output because I dont have reputation of 10 . I am very new

Comment: `dput(sortmax)` returns text, you'll be able to include it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you group your data only by one variable, you can also use `facet_wrap`. If 5 different Grade result in a too wide plot you can choose to add `nrow` or `ncol` (number of rows/columns) argument to adjust the final layout

Variant of rnso answer:

```
ggplot(data = sortmax, aes(x = Date, y = price, color=Grade)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point()+
    facet_wrap(~Grade,nrow=2)
```